# Why doesn't QTest allow const char* as a test data format?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

So I'm using Qt's QTest framework with the ["data driven" approach](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial2-example.html). I can define the test data like so:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (const int*);

void MyTest::testSomething_data ()
{
    QTest::addColumn<const int*> ("rawIntegerData");
    // ...
}
```

Now I try do to the same thing with `const char*` instead of `const int*`...

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (const char*);

void MyTest::testSomething_data ()
{
    QTest::addColumn<const char*> ("rawTextData");
    // ...
}
```

...and I get a failed static assertion:

```
const char* is not allowed as a test data format.
```

Turns out that QTest::addColumn *explicitly* rejects `const char*` in qtestcase.h.

I realize that `QByteArray` is probably a viable alternative, but I was wondering: what is the reason that `const char *` is not allowed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [the commit](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/commit/7cbdac13627b8e6ba9ed1bcd42fdf3f408f02b7d) message for that change:

> **Clarify assert on use of const char* as TestData type in tests.**
>
> Currently all C-style strings used as data types in QTest::addColumn
>   will assert at runtime with, e.g.: "expected data of type 'const
>   char*', got 'QString' for element 0 of data with tab 'blah'". This
>   patch makes it clear that C-style strings are disallowed.

There are some comments in the [Code Review here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/35995/)